# Removing transitions between media queries?

Tags: css

I have a `.hidden` div on small screens where visibility and opacity is transitioned based on a class called `.active`.

I need to transition visibility on small as to get a nice fade in/fade out when the `.active` class is added/removed.

```
.hidden{
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: visibility .3s, opacity .3s ease;
}
.hidden .active{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible
}
```

On larger screens I turn off the transition, and make `.hidden` visible all of the time:

```
.hidden{
    visibility: visible;
    transition: none;
}
```

The issue that I have is that when I go from large to small, `.hidden` transitions (fades out), and I want to have no transition.

So, how can I remove the transition when going between media queries?

Comment: Can you post the full code you have with the media queries please?

Comment: It's exactly as above, Ive described the media queries in the post.

Comment: Why don't you approach it so you only add the transition in the media queries that require it

Comment: Pete - that is how ive approached it, it's when you toggle between the media queries that the issue occurs.

Comment: @panthro in that case the only time it would transition would be moving from your larger size to your smaller size where the active ones would fade in - I don't see where your issue is with that

Comment: Add transition properties only in your target media query?

Answer (score 0):

you can use transition only in numerical values.
you can't use it in visibility.
try to use only opacity.